# awk can't get my for i loop to work

Tags: awk

I'm trying to loop in a log file and add occurrences of one of the field.

I know that the field #8 will have the occurrences I want to add, and that the field will contain a number between 1 and 924.

So far I had this awk one-liner:

```
awk '{count[$8]++}END{for(j in count) print j, count[j]" HIT"}' myfile.txt
```

But, I would like awk to output the numbers for witch it didn't find occurrences and print 0 next to it.

For example:

```
1 5 HIT
2 0 HIT
3 55 HIT
```

I tried this:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=924;i++) print i, count[$8]++}' myfile.txt
```

EDIT: I also tried this

```
awk '{count[$8]++}END{for(i=1;i<925;i++) print i, count[i]" HIT"}' myfile.txt
```

It gave me this:

```
919  HIT
920  HIT
921  HIT
922  HIT
923  HIT
924  HIT
```

And I'm sure there are counts for all of those.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
awk '{count[$8]++}END{for(i=1;i<925;i++) print i, count[i]" HIT"}' myfile.txt
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Comment: @shelter, I'm new to stackoverflow but not serverfault :) I tried the code you submitted but the count does not seem to print. I have a blank space on every line (see my edit).

Comment: @Alex: Hm.. My interpretation is that $8 contains value from 1-924. Is that correct? If so, then is it possible that there are extra chars (spaces most likely) in the $8 column? What is the FS value. You look to be using default of white-space. Is that correct?

Comment: @shelter, thanks a bunch...there where double quotes around the numbers...so changing the FS and adjusting the column did the trick!